# Navicat: Failed to save password Error code: -34018 on mac os

Tags: macos, keychain, navicat

I try to use navicat on mac os Big Sur but whene I put password get this error!

```
Failed to save password
Error code: -34018
```

Other apps work correctly!

Comment: did you find a fix for this?

Comment: Try to re-login to your navicat cloud. I did it and it works perfectly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After upgrading to MacOS Big Sur I had exactly the same error.

My solution was to override version 15.0.22 by an older version of Navicat (15.0.5 in my case). After replacing, the db configurations of version 15.0.22 still remains and I can save the password without any error.

Finally, I replaced Navicat version 15.0.5 by 15.0.22. When I opened Navicat again, the Keychain prompt was shown to type your login password to allow modifing your db password stored in Navicat.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem too.
But I solve it now.. What I did:

- Logout from Navicat Cloud
- Login Again
- Restart

It works now..