# navicat 15 macos big sur, Failed to save password Error code: - 34018

Tags: macos, macos-big-sur, navicat

I upgraded my mac to big sur and after that, I have a problem with Navicat, I can't save any password

Navicat error

> Failed to save password Error code: -34018

navicat version - 5.0.24

Could you help me resolve this issue?

Comment: did you manage to fix this?

Comment: this question could be help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959497/navicat-failed-to-save-password-error-code-34018-on-mac-os

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Navicat: Failed to save password Error code: -34018 on mac os](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64959497/navicat-failed-to-save-password-error-code-34018-on-mac-os)